# Detect CDC disconnection on STM32

Tags: usb, stm32, bare-metal

I have a [composite device](https://github.com/eddyem/stm32samples/tree/master/F3:F303/Seven_CDCs) on **bare-metal** STM32F303CBT6 (six USB CDC). It works and I can check connection to interface number X by getting `SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE` and `SET_LINE_CODING` requests with `wIndex==X`.
However I can't detect disconnection from given interface: I see no interrupts after client's terminal disconnected. Of course, as this is a composite device, there's also no suspend interrupts.
Is there any way to check terminal disconnection from given interface (e.g. when `/dev/ttyACM1` disconnected, I should have some signal, that interface 1 is no longer receiving data)?

**UPD**: I looked up through the sources of cdc-acm kernel module, on `close()` there's no any callbacks (for `BREAK`, `SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE` or so on). So, it seems like kernel module bug that don't allow to control client disconnection. To make proper device I should use emulation of PL2303.

Comment: `SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE` is the usual way to detect disconnection, but I think on Linux it depends on user-space program to actually set the control lines appropriately after connecting and before disconnecting.  In general, I'd recommend not relying on that though.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, yes, I found that sending of `SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE` depends on a port configuration. When my terminal software puts it into non-canonical mode, there's silence at disconnection, but in canonical mode all works fine. So, it seems like really theres no way to control user disconnection on CDC-ACM in Linux. I'd better continue to emulate PL2303 in my further work (kernel module automatically sends BREAK at disconnection event).

Comment: I think it's better to emulate a standard USB class (CDC) than some vendor-defined thing though.  You'll have better and longer-lasting driving support.  Seems like there are easier ways to work around this, like just design your CDC code to be non-blocking or fix whatever problem you're actually having (I'm not sure what the problem is).